# What is this macro #define type_string(name) { #name , name }

Tags: c, string, macros

Let's do the first example as simple as possible.

I want to know how to apply this macro; like here apply in e.g. `printf("%s",macro(arg));`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define type_string(name) { #name , name }

int main(void) {

char *hi = "Hello";    
char *arr[]=type_string(hi);
printf("%s\n",type_string(hi));

 return 0;
}
```

Also what could be other methods for printing the function' names:
My last solution is this one:

Is there a better way to optimize this code, like tweaking around `__func__`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


// let's declare different functions for calculation
int add(int x, int y);
int sub(int x, int y);
int mul(int x, int y);
int divide(int x, int y);

// let's declare function pointers to different behaviors
//int (*functionPtr_1[4])(int,int);                            // basic form
typedef int (*myFuncDef)(int, int);                       // typedef as the basic form
int do_calculations (int (*functionPtr)(int, int));       // function receives function pointer with two args and returns int
int (*functionFactory(int n))(int, int);



int main() {
    int m = 6;
    int n = 10;
    int res,i;

    int (*functionPtr_arr[4])(int,int) = {&add, &sub, &mul, &divide};

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        res=(*functionPtr_arr[i])(4,5);
    }
}

int add(int x, int y) {
int result = x + y;
printf("result for %s op is %d\n",__func__,result);
return result;
}

int sub(int x, int y) {
int result = x - y;
printf("result for %s op is %d\n",__func__,result);
return result;
}

int mul(int x, int y) {
int result = x * y;
printf("result for %s op is %d\n",__func__,result);
return result;
}

int divide(int x, int y) {
int result = x / y;
printf("result for %s op is %d\n",__func__,result);
return result;
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the context in which the macro is used, it works by textual substitution. In this case the context and the result of the substitution is rather trivial. Which specific part do you find difficult to understand?

Comment: It is impossible to answer the second part of the question without knowning what the purpose of the `fns` array is. If you just want to "print the function names", then you can use the second code. If the purpose is to create a name-to-function mapping (which is actually what `fns` looks like), then your second version is completely inapplicable because it does not do that. What specifically are you trying to achieve? Without knowing that there no way to suggest how to "optimize" the code.

Comment: @AnT For your first comment, it's a textual substitution, what I want to understand is that I now understood that this value is considered to be groups of elements in an array, so that how the author initialize the struct array, I also learned that in the element array I can substitute with a string, number or function name. But how can I substitute with variables names?

Comment: I still don't understand the focus of the question. The textual sunstitution is rather trivial and produces snippets like `{ "fna", fna }`, `{ "fnb", fnb }` and so on, which later act as brace-enclosed initializers in array initialization. So, what is your question really about: how textual substuitution works or how brace-enclosed initializers in array initialization work? What does "substitute with variables names" mean? What "variables names" exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @AnT For your second comment, well the second code was a suggestion example from one of the members for how to display functions' names where I was asking about ____func____ and to substitute it in a for loop in main function instead of substitution for each function.

Comment: Yes, how to substitute with variables names. Because I now can substitute with a string, function name or integer, so what other things I can substitute in the macro?

Comment: I edited the first code, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

`#define FN_RECORD(f) { #f, f }`
This macro works by taking a variable in, f, and putting that value into what it is replacing.

Ex.

Having a function `int abc(void);`

Putting `FN_RECORD(abc)` into your code will be replaced with `{ "abc", abc }` after pre-processing. The `#` creates a string.

It appears that the person who created this macro intended it to be used as the name of a function as a c-string, along with it's function pointer.

Comment: But how to apply it without including it in the array as in the first code example? I tried but couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

The comment describing the macro is remarkably clear, so it is not certain what you might be confused by.

In context it is used to generate initialisers for the `fns` array.  So:

```
fn_record fns[3] = {                        
    FN_RECORD(fna),
    FN_RECORD(fnb),
    FN_RECORD(fnc) 
};
```

Expands to:

```
fn_record fns[3] = {                        
    {"fna", fna},
    {"fnb", fnb},
    {"fnc", fnc} 
};
```

The comment says it is to save you typing, but that is a rather silly reason - its hardly a valuable time-saving.  What it does usefully do is ensure that the string and the function name match to avoid possible errors.

Comment: I tried to apply this macro outside the struct but I couldn't.

Comment: @PerchEagle The macro can be expanded anywhere.  But if, e.g., `{"fna", fna}` doesn't make sense in that context, it will fail to compile.  You can compile with `gcc -E foo.c` to see what the code looks like after all the preprocessing if you can't tell why it's failing to compile.  (This will also include all the headers, so there'll be a lot of cruft at the beginning.)

Comment: @PerchEagle : Why would you expect the macro to make any syntactic sense outside of its intended context?  Macros are not functions; they are text replacements that must be syntactically valid _after_ expansion.  Sometimes macros have function-like behaviour - this is not one of them;  its function-like syntax is somewhat misleading in this case.

Comment: @Ray Why it would fail? I mean what I understood by defined macros that you can apply them any where in the code. So, in the first example, the author included them in a struct typedef array! How that is possible? What are the possible location to apply those macros with functions' names as arguments?

Comment: @Clifford Because what I understand of macros that they work anywhere because they just substitute the value they represent! But wait!! This macro represent an array elements, so they can't be located anywhere, they have to be located in proper locations as elements e.g. arrays, initializations to variables and other similar locations.

Comment: @PerchEagle The macro operates on raw text (technically tokens, but let's ignore that for now) and generates other raw text.  Then the compiler acts as though you had just typed the text the macro generated.  If the macro generates code that makes sense in a struct typedef array, then it'll work in that context.

Comment: @PerchEagle : The "work anywhere" in the sense that the pre-processor will blindly expand any instance. Whether such an expansion makes any syntactic or semantic sense is a different matter. Note also, not quite anywhere, not in a literal string or comment.

Comment: @Ray OK, I understand that the macro is substituting with a text whether it generates a code or anything; like, number or a snippet. But what I want to understand now is the code I edited now in the main post, the first code, I concluded last night to this simple code just to know how this curly braces with # works. I want to know if I can substitute with a variable name.

Comment: @Clifford Yeah, that's a tough one to know what locations which a macro would work and others which don't. Hmmmm, if you would see the main post I edited the first code with more simple one I was working on last night, I hope you understand what I want to do.

Comment: I want to know what is the name of this macro technique?

Comment: @PerchEagle I don't think I can explain this properly in comments (Especially since I'm not entirely sure where the point of confusion is).  I've added an answer where I break down what happens step-by-step.  Let me know which part's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down one step at a time.

```
#define type_string(name) { #name , name }

int main(void) {
    char *hi = "Hello";    
    char *arr[]=type_string(hi);
    printf("%s\n",type_string(hi));
}
```

Compilation happens in two stages (three, if you count linking, but let's ignore that).  The preprocessor and compiler are actually separate programs in a lot of cases, but the compiler runs the preprocessor automatically.

### Preprocessing

First, we do all preprocessing.  So let's look at what happens then:

```
char *arr[]=type_string(hi);
```

The token `hi` is passed to `type_string`.  The fact that `hi` is a variable doesn't matter; `name` contains `hi`, not `"Hello"`.

- # is the stringification operator.  Since `name` is `hi`, `#name` evaluates to `"hi"`.
- `name` just evaluates to `hi`.

So `type_string(hi)` as a whole evaluates to `{ "hi" , hi }`, and the line as a whole becomes `char *arr[]={ "hi" , hi };`.  `printf("%s\n", type_string(hi));` works the same way, and becomes `printf("%s\n", { "hi" , hi });`.

### Compiling

Now that preprocessing is done, the *actual* compiler gets to go.  This is what the compiler will see:

```
int main(void) {
    char *hi = "Hello";    
    char *arr[]={ "hi" , hi };
    printf("%s\n",{ "hi" , hi });
}
```

`{ "hi", hi }` will evaluate to an array of `char*`; the first element implicitly points to the (constant) string literal `"hi"`, and the second element initialized to the address currently contained in `hi`, which happens to be the address of the string literal `"Hello"`.

Naturally, this won't work; `printf("%s\n", { "hi" , hi })` is expecting a string and gets an array literal, which isn't legal in that context.

You could instead do `printf("%s, %s\n", arr[0], arr[1]);`, which would print `hi, Hello`.